# Use "Team Members" custom post type instead of Author for blog posts

Tags: wordpress

For SEO purposes....a client would like to have author links point to the Team member's bio page instead of the default author page....for example:

There's a blog posts written by  user A. The author link now points to:

`/author/usera`

but they would like it to point to

`/our-team/user-a`

"Our Team" is a custom post type, and User A is a post within it.

I've tried a few workaround solutions, but haven't found a good way to establish the relationship between the author and the team member. If I could just add the team member from that custom post type when choosing the Author...that would solve my problem, though I imagine that's fairly complicated - but hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

My workaround so far is to rewrite the author base to the slug of the custom post type, which takes care of half of it, but there's still no relationship between the author and team member, so I use `the_author_meta(user_url)` to get the "Website" field in the user profile, and I put in the url of the team member there.

It works, but doubles the work since you have to add the Team Member to Our Team, as well as add them as a user/author, and then requires the knowledge of the admin adding the user/author to add the bio url in the website field, otherwise...it won't work well, so I'd love a cleaner solution.

Let me know if that makes any sense or not and if there's a better way to do this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I cannot see an automated mapping of user account → team member post happening. So, there are multiple ways to achieve this by manually mapping user accounts to a team member post.

1. Set the author's website to the URL of the team page
2. Advanced Custom Fields: creating a field group that is shown for all user accounts and includes a Post field (limited to Team posts), so you can select exactly one team post for each WP user manually

I will show you the first option.

Assume, each user account (Users) has the URL to the team member page set, e.g., in the user profile of `usera` you see:
Website: https://your-site/our-team/user-a

Then you can add a filter to modify the author link like so, adding this to your functions.php or own plugin:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'team_author_link', 10, 3 );
function team_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ) {

  $userinfo = get_userdata($author_id);
  // if the user's Website field is not empty, replace the author link:
  $link = empty($userinfo->data->user_url) ? $link : $userinfo->data->user_url;
  return $link;
}
```

Now, you will have all your author's links linked to their "website", which hopefully has been set to the team member page.

This can also be done with Advanced Custom Fields a bit prettier where you could add a field group shown for User Roles -> All, with the field group having a "Post"-type field named "team_post", matching only the team custom post type. It would look similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLgWv.png
(your post type most likely will not display as "Staff member", but most likely "Team").

Then, you can select a Team post in each author's user profile and change the filter function to this:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'team_author_link', 10, 3 );
function team_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ) {

  $team_post_id = get_field('team_post', $author_id);
  // if the team post is set, get the permalink to the team post:
  $team_link = get_permalink($team_post_id);
  $link = ($team_link !== false) ? $team_link : $link;
  return $link;
}
```

Keep in mind that in both cases, each user can tamper with their URL. Using Advanced Custom Fields, it would also be possible to create an admin-only options page where you can map user accounts to Team posts - but this is a bit more complex.

Comment: You are missing the `user_` prefix before the author ID in `get_field()`